# Detect which event finishes activity

Tags: android

How to detect the what event causes activity finish/onstop called.In the case of back button pressed,home key pressed,user navigates from notification bar.How can i detect these three cases when the activity is called stop.(ICS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override onKeyDown method of View, and catch there back and home buttons as well as others. You should remember to return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); after you mark somewhere what key was pressed. That way, default action will continue.

Important for it to work is calling requestFocus() on your view. In other case it would not receive any key presses and do not call any of your callbacks.

You should be able to know back was pressed, home was pressed or something else got on top of your activity. That is when no home or back was detected and Activity.onStop() was called. I hope you are looking for this.

Comment: it doesnt work...onKeyDown doesnt listen to back key and home key

Comment: I am sure SurfaceView is able to receive KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK and pass to your application. Maybe it will work only in focusOnTouch mode.I am sure it works for me, maybe with ICS 4.0 it might behave differently. Of course we have application as single view and all interfaces are drawn into surface by custom library, such way might be unacceptable to you.
Try:
        view.setFocusable(true);
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocusFromTouch();

Answer (score 1):

If the user leaves with the back key then the `onDestroy()` method will be called.

But I'm not sure whether it's possible to make the distinction between the last 2 cases (home key and notification)

Comment: that sounds good answer,but i need other two cases specially... !  :(

Answer (score 0):

You should check below link and download the sample project

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html